# How to send Data to a restful web service from android app?

Tags: android, web-services

I have created several web services but I don't know how to code my android app to connect and send data to it.

I am a graduate and a Beginner At Android development (I am not using Jersey API)

Example of my working service. (JSON Format)

Create Customer

service :http://108.168.203.227/meetandgreet/Customer.svc/CreateCustomer

e.g.

**Input:**

```
{

    "objCustomerModel": {
        "FirstName": "Harry",
        "LastName": "Potter",
        "EmailId": "potter@gmail.com",
        "ContactNo": "98765432165",
        "Address1": "11 address",
        "Address2": "22 address",
        "Password": "123456"
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Insertion : {"CreateCustomerResult":{"Id":"19","Message":"","Status":"0"}}

Duplicate: {"CreateCustomerResult":{"Id":"19","Message":"","Status":"1"}}

Error: {"CreateCustomerResult":{"Id":null,"Message":"will show error message here","Status":"-1"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that it's web service based on standard HTTP protocol, you can use low-level java net library(URL, URLConnection, URLEncoder/URLDecoder) to invoke the service.
Also, many Android developers use the high-level library named httpclient http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: I more confused on how to post the data from the app? I have been able to get data from my other services to the app. But coding the app to send the data (post) in the example above confuses me.

Comment: Would you have an example?